# How do I add space between my radio buttons? (HTML)

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I currently have 3 radio buttons of genders but they are all too close to each other, I want a good amount of gap between the text of one Radiobutton and the other Radiobutton.

```css
.radio {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.radio-group {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.radio span {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label class="label control - label">Gender</label>
<div class="radio-group">
  <label>
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value = "male"/>
       Male
       <span></span>
 </label>
  <label>
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value = "female"/>
       Female
       <span></span>
  </label>
  <label>
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value = "Other"/>
       Other
       <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

I tried margins and padding and looked at some other stack questions which are quite similar but they dont really seem to work for some reason, what do I do?

Comment: None of your rules use the wrapping label as target. Did you try margins on those?

Comment: what do you mean? I am sorry I am new to web programming so could you please elaborate..

Comment: Not really sure what you are needing to be honest. Note you have `.radio` class selector rules but no such class in the html. For a radio input element you can use `input[type=radio]` as selector or actually give them a class

Comment: @charlietfl ohhhh! I see! thing is, this code is from a youtube video - as I said im a beginner so I am trying to get a Hang of things. the input[type = radio] worked thank. you! and I removed .radio as well

Comment: Might want to study some css selector tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that? (with css [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after))

```css
.radio-group {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.radio-group label::after {
  content:'\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0'; /* eq &nbsp; x 4 */
}

/* optionnal */
.radio-group label:last-of-type::after {
  content:'';
}
```

```html
<label class="label control - label">Gender</label>
<div class="radio-group">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
    Male
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
    Female
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other">
    Other
  </label>
</div>
```